# why 1*1 layer after max-pooling in inception network

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I understand that in inception network, 1 * 1 layer is used before 3 * 3 or 5 * 5 filter to do some channel reduction and make computation easier. But why max-pooling then 1 * 1 layer? In particular, why not 1 * 1 before max-pooling? and is this 1 * 1 used to increase channel after dimension reduction in height and width?